# How to host multiple websites as sub domains on IIS?

Tags: iis, web-hosting

I'm trying to host two websites in IIS

**https ://one.invalid.domain** (port 44301) and 
**https ://two.invalid.domain** (port 44302)

I have tried to add port and host name binding. 
I did ipconfig /flashdns

However I am not able to navigate to the website from the browser. But if I put port number such as **https ://one.domain.com:44301** then the browser loads the page,

How do I configure it so I don't have to put the port number in the browser.

There is just one public IP and A name records pointing to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify the port number in the browser then the browser silently assumes port 443 for the HTTPS protocol. This means you need to setup the IIS binding on port 443 as well.

If you want to host multiple websites on the same port then make sure you include the host header in the binding and enable SNI (supported on IIS 8 and above).